# Stop YouTube video on modal close - after AJAX load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube

I have a small script that stops YouTube videos from playing after their modals are closed. The issue is it doesn't work if the HTML has been loaded via AJAX.

Script:

```
$('#panelModal-1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    callPlayer('yt-player-1', 'stopVideo');
});
$('#panelModal-2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    callPlayer('yt-player-2', 'stopVideo');
});
```

HTML (curly braces denote data pulled from CMS):

```
<li>
  <a href="#" title="Watch Video" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#panelModal-{count}">
    <div class="video-background" style="background-image:url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/{video_youtube_id}/hqdefault.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="video-details">
      <h4>{title}</h4>
      <p>{video_subtitle}</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="panelModal-{count}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel-{count}">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel-{count}">{title}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="yt-player-{count}" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{video_youtube_id}?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

The AJAX part is this:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('.sub-nav').delegate('.load-case-studies', 'click', function(e)
    {
        // Don't follow the link
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.sub-nav a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        // Fetch the next page
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data)
        {                                           
            // Only grab the part of the page we want
            content = $(data).find('.ajax-wrapper').hide();

            // Add it to the DOM
            $(content).replaceAll('#entry-container');

            // Fade-in our new content
            $(content).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

How can I get the videos to stop playing after the modal is closed, if the data has been loaded via AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use following jQuery command.

```
$('#playerID').get(0).stopVideo();
```

If your using Player API :

```
var player = new YT.Player('player');    
player.stopVideo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Global Event Handlers .ajaxComplete, .ajaxSuccess

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
      $('#videoModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
          this.querySelector('video').pause();
      });
  });
```